# Json response giving an error of Invalid email address using PHP GET method in sendgrid api

Tags: php, json

i'm using sendgrid api for sending emails. when i'm trying to send a signle email then it's working fine & when i'm trying to send mutiple email id's mannualy then it's also working fine.
But the problem is when i' requesting email from database and wanna send it throught api,the json response giving me an error or invalid email address.

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/ph6i2n

below are my codes:

```
<?php
include_once "config/connect.php";
$eid=$_REQUEST['eid'];
$q="Select * from email where eid='$eid'";
$qr=mysqli_query($mysql,$q) or die($q.mysqli_error($mysql));
while($r=mysqli_fetch_object($qr))
{
    $id       = $r->id;
    $emails   = $r->email;
    $message1 = $r->body;
    $subject1 = $r->subject;
    $attechment = $r->attechment;
}

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';

$fileName = $attechment;
//$filePath = dirname('/uploads/attechment');
$filePath = 'http://localhost/projects5/crm1/folder/dash/uploads/attechment';
//$list = array('$emails');



$json_string = array(

  'to' => array($emails),
  'category' => 'test_category'
);


$params = array(
    'api_user'  => $user,
    'api_key'   => $pass,
    'to'        => $emails,
    'x-smtpapi' => json_encode($json_string), 
    'subject'   => $subject1,
    'html'      => '<p> the HTML </p>',
    'text'      => 'the plain text',
    'from'      => 'example@wephyre.com',
    //'files['.$fileName.']' => '@'.$filePath.'/'.$fileName
   'files['.$fileName.']' => file_get_contents($filePath.'/'.$fileName)
  );

print_r($params);

$request =  $url.'api/mail.send.json';

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);

// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
// Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

// print everything out
print_r($response);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

just solved by myself, this is because of quotes, the jsaon expects the values as string.

```
$string = "'" . str_replace(array("'", ","), array(",'", "','"), $emails) . "'";

$json_string = array(

  'to' => array($string),
  'category' => 'test_category'
);
```

Comment: you may do this: at query level to avoid this replacements :

Answer (score 0):

May be solved by modifying at query level using single quotes in where clause like below:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 
            " . $this->table_name . " 
            WHERE email =  '".$this->email."'  LIMIT 0,1";
```